# Exchange parts of strings in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

is there a way to transfer characters in the a plain .txt file.

I have a lot of entries in the .txt file and they are all in this format:

- 1 = Example,
- 2 = Example2,
- 3 = Example3...

what I need is a batch file to transfer "# =" to the right side of the string. So it looks like this:

- Example = 1,
- Example2 = 2...

Is it possible to that with a .bat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will handle more than one word where you have `Example...`

```
@echo off 
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%a in (input.txt) do >>output.txt echo %%b = %%a
```

Comment: I also tried using that on  a test file I made. Inside I've put "1 = Example" and ran the batch on it, nothing happened.

Comment: @hobbilis Try it now - it only printed to the screen earlier.  Now it writes into an output.txt file.

Comment: Awesome, it is working now. Thanks, you saved me so much time. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use GNU [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed "s/\(\S\+\)\s=\s\(\S\+\)/\2 = \1/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@echo off

pushd "C:\some\where"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%b = %%a
popd
```

Or use this to get rid of whitespace:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "C:\some\where"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  set "key=%%a"
  set "val=%%b"
  echo !val: =! = !key: =!
)
popd
```

To save the output to a file, call either script like this:

```
switch.cmd >output.txt
```

Comment: I tried both of your codes, but unfortunately nothing worked. It went through the my .txt file and didn't change anything.

Comment: The scripts just echo the transformed lines to the console. If you want the output in a file, redirect it (see updated answer).

Comment: I've already modified your first code so it makes an output right away.

`@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "C:\Users\Hobbilis\Desktop"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  set "key=%%a"
  set "val=%%b"
  echo !val: =! = !key: =!>>output.txt
)
popd`